# Can Google Drive Services Account open files?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

[image]I created an Service Account and currently I can login into my Google Drive, post, delete, edit files and folders.
But when I try to access a file, folders works just fine, I get error 401 unauthorized.
My service account has "editor" privilegies and I set the account to "Restricted" which "Only people with access can open with the link".

When I set the account to "Anyone with the link", Anyone on the internet with the link can view I can open the files using my service account, no problem.

So, how can I open/view my files using a service account and having the account set to "Restricted"?

Editing: Adding more information
I would like to share how I am trying to access the files:
Once we create a file to google drive it generates a field called: webViewLink which if you paste in the browser you can open it.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you trying to access the file, can you share the code you're working with? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: a service account is not you it must be pre-authorized to access files on your personal drive account.   share the file with the service account like you would any other user

Comment: Thank you @LorenaGomez! I did not provide any piece of code because everything is working fine... I just wanted to know if is possible to view a file by using a service account and having the settings set to "restricted".

Comment: @AndreMachadodoMonte If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74140814/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Or if you have questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A service account is a type of Google account that can be used by an application to access Google APIs programmatically, it's not possible to open a file with a service account from a browser. As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#differences_between_a_service_account_and_a_user_account):

> Service accounts do not have passwords, and cannot log in via browsers or cookies.

If you're using a Google Workspace account, you can authorize a service account to access data on behalf of a user in the domain. You can see more information [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority).